# How to solve the below Recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis, recurrence

consider the recurrence equation, provided in the  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MohEX.png). This doesn't fit into the form required by the Master Theorem. i don't want to use the substitution method as it is time-consuming. Also i tired by changing the variable (k=2^m), but failed.

How to solve this through **recursion tree or iteration method**?

```
 T(n) =n^0.5  T(n^0.5) + n
```

p.s :
expected solution is : **O(nlglgn)**

Comment: Square root corresponds to `^(1/2)` not `^(3/2)`.

Comment: oops sorry ,editing

Comment: An answer like O(nlglgn) corresponds to a question like 'bound' or 'compute an asymptotic' of the function T defined by the recurrence. It is not 'solving' it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let U(n) = T(n)/n.

Then U(n) = n<sup>1/2</sup>T(n<sup>1/2</sup>)/n + 1, and so

U(n) = T(n<sup>1/2</sup>)/n<sup>1/2</sup> + 1

U(n) = U(n<sup>1/2</sup>) + 1

It's easy enough to find by the iteration method that U(n) <= log log n + U(2), because that's how many times you can take the square root of n before you get to 2 (using log base 2).  You could then prove this inductively for all n > 2 if required.

You therefore have T(n) = U(n)*n <= n (log log n + T(2)/2), and that is in O(n log log n)

Comment: from where i asked this, it had a solution : T(n) = O(nlglgn).

Comment: Oops. I solved to wront recurrence ;-) .  Fixed it.

Comment: understood. Thanks